# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘projects’: Permission denied in Git Complete: The Definitive, Step-By-Step Guide

Tags: directory, mkdir, projects

I'm following the *Git Complete: The Definitive, Step-By-Step Guide* offered through stackskills. The author is Jason Taylor.

These are the first commands he give once gitbash is installed.

```
pwd
mkdir projects
cd projects
pwd
```

I get this everytime:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘projects’: Permission denied

I'd like to continue the course, but there is no help forum.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run these commands?

Comment: You left out the output from `pwd`, which shows you what directory you're in. It's relevant. Why did you not show the response from either one of them? The four commands work fine on my system using Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

you have launch gitbash as an administrator. just make a right click on the bash icon on start menu or taskbar, then you ll see the option.